# magento 2.4.2-p2 setup issue on wamp server local

Tags: magento2.4.2, wamp

I am using a wamp server and its PHP version is 7.4.9 I am trying to install Magento version-2.4.2 in window 10. But I am facing this problem. I have found several solutions to install libosodium extension on the internet to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to share more details about your issue. Preferably a screenshot of CLI where installation progress is showing.Is it either Hosting configuration issue or magento 2 setup issue. You can check var/log files to find the installation error log trail.

Comment: extension=php_libsodium.dll
extension=sodium this both line add in php.ini file also wampp server restart